# Displaying a Dash view of one application only?

Tags: gnome-shell, activities-overview

When we hit the windows key we see all the currently opened applications.  Is there a way to see only the windows for one app?

For example I just want to see all the Chrome windows I have opened and filter out everything else.

Comment: How is the OS supposed to guess which app you want?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia what about based on the currently active window? Would actually be good to be able to spread windows of the same application. That said, no, this is not implemented in Gnome Shell.

Comment: Indeed - We could press shift + window or something to see all the currently active windows in Chrome.  Going to have to do a Gnome Feature request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how to do it, but when I wanna view all tabs from the same app, I use *Alt + Tab* then I select this app (chrome) and press *arrow-bottom*, 
then I can see all the pages that I opened and I can switch between them.

Comment: What the OP asks is not currently implemented in Gnome Shell (aka, it is not possible), but indeed Alt+Tab (or directly Alt+Above_tab) allows you to see little window previews of your current application.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for a way to achieve this and ended up hacking s.th. together: https://github.com/freder/application-windows-overview

Comment: that's exactly what I want, many times